# onCreate.identityType=role not the first one

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I'm using v. 2.2.11
I've got a problem using `onCreate.identityType`.
The documentation says:

```
onCreate.identityType: Specifies whether to insert the user's object or its role (the first one). By default, it is set to user, but you can also set it to use its role.
```

But it's not true, I've got a user with multiple roles and inserting a new record into a `ORestricted` class it takes randomly on of them.
Here what I did:

- create a new db
- create class test extends ORestricted
- ALTER CLASS test CUSTOM `onCreate.identityType`=role
- insert into ouser set name='test',password='test',status='ACTIVE',roles=(select from orole where name in ['reader','writer'])
- Logged with test user
- insert into test set now=sysdate() (x 10 times)

Casually _allow field contains #4:1 or #4:2

Is it a bug? 
If not, any suggestion for making it work like written in the documentation?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue, but at third step when I'm altering class test, I'm getting the error about the dot in: `onCreate.identityType` both in studio and console.

Comment: You're right! This's the right syntax: 
ALTER CLASS test CUSTOM \`onCreate.identityType`=role...

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your "issue", I think documentation refers to first object or role, and not first role of two roles. There is no need to use both reader and writer roles, since writer also can do read operations. If you want only reader role you can just use

```
insert into ouser set name='test',password='test',status='ACTIVE',roles=(select from orole where name in ['reader'])
```

Comment: Sorry but I disagree.
If what you say is true, why specify "...(the first one)..."? The first one of what?
Then, of course I don't need both reader and writer, it was just an example, I only needed to 2 roles...
So, back to the "issue", any solution?